# Place all items in the center of the screen using CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

So basically what i want to do is to have 9 Boxes in the middle of the screen.

This is what i tried:

```css
main {
  border: 4px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.box2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

.box3 {
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="box1">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
  </div>


  <div class="box1">
    <h1>Box 4</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <h1>Box 5</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box3">
    <h1>Box 6</h1>
  </div>


  <div class="box1">
    <h1>Box 7</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <h1>Box 8</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box3">
    <h1>Box 9</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

This almost does what i want.

So what i get is this:

### -b-b-b-

### -b-b-b-

### -b-b-b-

with - being free space.

What i want is this:

### -bbb-

### -bbb-

### -bbb-

so that the 9 boxes actually touch each other.

Is there a way to do that?

(i want to hold on to the `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` and `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr`)

tyvm :)

Comment: `auto` instead of `1fr`

Comment: Your grid setup is okay, just set the boxes 100% width and height.

Comment: looks exactly the same :/

Comment: But i want them to not be bigger than 50%

Comment: Use a 5 column grid?

Comment: That would work but in the setting i actually want to use this this wouldn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that? (i want to hold on to the `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` and `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr`)

No. There is no way to do this.

Because you've set your columns to `1fr` each, they will spread across the width of the container in equal lengths. Therefore, the columns are not centered.

You would have to do something like this: `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto auto 1fr`, with the `1fr` columns having no content and used solely for spacing. This set up would pin the three inner columns to the center.